# windows 10 - UWP - drop down button

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10

I'm trying to have a **'drop down button'**.

I don't know if the is the good naming, but I need to have :

[image]

But I really have no idea how to do it, or even how this is named.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you check this Link? https://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/uwp-custom-control-expandable-row-listview/

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly what is on your mock, but what about MenuFlyout? It's almost the same and you don't need any magic for that. Plus it feels native for UWP users:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button 1">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Action 1"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Action 2"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Action 3"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button 2"/>
    <Button Content="Button 3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is API addition with DropDownButton in [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 17686](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/06/12/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-17686-available-now/) (line 487).

```
public class DropDownButton : Button
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a while, but for anyone wondering, the image drawn more accurately represents a tree hierarchy then anything else

Try "TreeView" from there its standard intuitive coding